# React hooks: 'TypeError: Object is not a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React version 16.13.1.

I'm getting 'TypeError: Object is not a function'

Here is my code (error message seems to think something is wrong with line 7):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import fb from '../config/firebase';
import ProcessInput from './customHooks/processInput';

const DashBoard = ({ level, newUser }) => {

  const [val, bind] = ProcessInput('');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Here is my custom hook:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const ProcessInput = value => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(value);

  return {
    val,
    setVal,
    bind: {
      val,
      onChange: event => {
        setVal(event.target.value);
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post actual code, not pictures of it.

Comment: Names of custom hooks should start with `use`, see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ProcessInput is returning an object, but you are destructuring it to an array.

Try this:

```
const {val, bind} = ProcessInput('');
```

Comment: That's a good point, but it's not the case since he is not receiving "_object is not iterable_" error.

Comment: I would have thought so too @kinduser but this worked for me. Thanks !